# Select element onchange

Tags: javascript, select, element

How can i acces an select element if it has been selected?

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
if(select.selected == true)

doesnt work any idea?
```

Comment: Could we know what is the type of the element that you are trying to select example like checkbox , radiobutton etc ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

document.getElementById("mySelect").value

or

var selObj = document.getElementById("mySelect");
selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: I normally would have an item at the start of the list such as [Select Value]. Then you test for selectedIndex > 0

Answer (score 0):

The DOM tree is something like

```
Select
|-option
|-option
`-option
```

it is not the select node which can be selected. As such, you need to get the select, browse the childs, and test if the child is selected until you find one.